# Compatibity Mode for IE 10 using meta tag

Tags: asp.net, browser, cross-browser, iis-6, backwards-compatibility

Basically I have this website that has been working very well in compatible mode IE7 for all versions of IE(I have used meta tag in IIS for this).

Now issue is with IE10 where document mode is changing to IE Standards but Browser mode is not changing to be compatible.

Can you please guide me to a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tag would change document mode for you whereas you still need to have fixed your application or server, this is a known issue.

[This](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) would fix browser mode and combining it with meta tag below would do the job for you.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```