# IE8 issue - Some images and styles are working, others aren't

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I don't understand why some images and styles are working on IE8 and others aren't in the same page of the same website!

http://www.chrissteeleperkins.com/

The homepage is fine but the images in the footer are missing in the whole website.

If you go to other pages of the website, sometimes the css style looks to be missing.

This weird behaviour seems to appear on IE8 - Windows 7.

Any help or suggestions?

Thank you,
Giorgio

Comment: Don't know if this is related to your problem but you are using pretty new jquery version but an old version of fancybox. The old fancybox version is trying to access a function that does not exist in jquery anymore (msie). You should update fancybox.

Comment: Good spot, thanks but I don't have Fancybox installed in all the pages though. Just in one of them. When I use Compatibility view on IE8 some issues are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The homepage is fine but the images in the footer are missing in the whole website.

Seems, that problem is with `float: left` in `<li>` elements. Try fixing size of blocks or make elements inline;

Comment: I tried to make the elements inline but it's not fixing the issue. If I remove the float:left; to the <li> elements, the issue is solved, but they won't be aligned to the left. So I tried to put an empty div with clear: both; but it didn't fix it.

Comment: I managed to fix the floating issue but I still don't understand why in the other pages like http://www.chrissteeleperkins.com/about/ there is no css while in http://www.chrissteeleperkins.com/services/ some of css style is ok. Why this issue? Is there something to do with relative path ../ to the css styles - images are fine though?

Comment: I could see in the source code in IE8 that the opening <nav> becomes </nav>. So the opening tag is </nav> and the closing tag is </nav> as well - in the code it's correct though. In fact if you do a comparison with another browser, it doesn't seem to be wrong. I tried to change the code copying and pasting the line of code from a page that displays correctly but has still the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: <nav> is HTML5 tag. You need to add libraries for this tag to your <head> element. Try downloading them and add like this:

`<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>   
    <![endif]-->`

Comment: You will need `html5shiv.js` and `respond.min.js`

Comment: Your suggestions were very helpful! Those fixed the issues! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is compatibility of your css/javascript with upper versions of IE, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150943/87956) should help you out.

Above is just a work around better way would be to fix your css and javascript/jquery to take care of compatibility issues.