# Why ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock In UserControl Is not working after deployed my code to server.in IE11?

Tags: c#

My server side code in ascx.cs file...When i clickedon image the event is firing but it is not able to calling the  "CallAFPopup();" Javascript method.

```
void btnSelectAccountFamily_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) != null)
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(ImageButton), "onclick", "CallAFPopup();", true);
}
```

It works fine in IE8,IE9,and other browsers but not in IE11

Comment: Check you console for javascript error, RegisterClientScriptBlock works with IE 11 but if you have other javascript error then that maybe the cause.

Comment: I have done that also but i didnt get any error in IE11 Console.I Have tried all Examples.one thing is it is working on Visual Studio but not on server.Please i dont undesratnd why it is happening.by the same time I used RegisterStartupScript this method insted of that.it is working fine but i have one more problem in this method that The Usecontrol is displaying all Elements at while posting back.Actually it should not happen.because it feels bad behaviour of the Page

Comment: Your css/javascript is broken as per IE 11, you need to fix your code or use compatibility view. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19150943/87956

Comment: Hi Thanks,but FYI The Application has to work in IE11 Edge Mode in non compatibility mode